# Doubling a list in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm trying to add the same copy of a list to itself to double its size.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
```

I'm trying to double the y_train list and basically combine two copies of itself by doing

```
augmented_y_train = y_train + y_train
```

But oddly enough, this doesn't work because when I check the lengths

```
len(y_train)
len(augmented_y_train)
```

They both output 2500, when it should be 2500 and 5000

When I do this with a normal list in python, this works fine, for example

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
c = a
print(b+c)
# output is [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

I know I could just redownload the training list again as a different object and then python will treat it like a completely different list and then combine the two.  And this should work, but I'm wondering why the simpler solution of adding lists doesn't work here? I think it has something to do with np arrays and the fact that the variables are pointing to the same object but it seems like there should be a simple tweak to still get it to work.

Comment: Research how Python lists implement `+`, and how `numpy.array` implement it

Comment: ahh, I see it now, I was doubly confused because when I did the same thing with my augmented X train data, it had no problems but that was because when I was augmenting the x_train, I had turned it into a list.

Comment: can you test the two list shape (y_train.shape .. etc ?

Comment: @pippo1980 I checked the shape and everything matches up now

Answer (score 0):

Numpy treats the `+` sign as element-wise addition between lists. Meanwhile python concatenates them. To concatenate arrays in numpy, you would do

```
augmented_y_train = np.concatenate((y_train, y_train))
```